# Php Blowfish decryption scrambling data

Tags: php, blowfish, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to encrypt an xml string, save it somewhere, and then decrypt it later (using blowfish in cbc mode).

When I decrypt the string, it scrambles the first 4 characters.

```
$text = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> ....";
$td = mcrypt_module_open('blowfish', '', 'cbc', '');
$iv = 'kd84h28v';
$ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
$key = substr(md5('randomString1234'), 0, $ks);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$cypher = mcrypt_generic($td, $text);
print mdecrypt_generic($td, $cypher);

# prints: çGÖºÌrsion="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

I would use `ecb` mode instead - which decrypts fine - except the current php implementation ignores the iv.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ECB doesn't support an IV, it's not an implementation detail. That's like saying "I would ride a motorcycle, except the current Honda models don't come with four wheels."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/mdecrypt_generic):

> It is very important to reinitialize the encryption buffer with
>   mcrypt_generic_init() before you try to decrypt the data.

So you probably need something like this:

```
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$cypher = mcrypt_generic($td, $text);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
print mdecrypt_generic($td, $cypher);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Though I wonder why I didn't need that to decrypt ecb?

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with different ways of padding, but I don't know enough about the mcrypt internals to state that with any confidence.